# Why won't my Duplicate Rule fire?

Tags: account, configuration, duplicate-management, setup, dupeblocker

[image]I created a new Duplicate Rule for Account that should fire when an Account has the same (Name and Site) or (Name and Billing City). A custom matching rule was made however the rule still will not fire when I test it. I have been testing by creating 2 Accounts with the same Name and Site. [image: Dupe Rule and Matching Rule]

Comment: Notice you have Action on Create = Allow. Are you trying to get it to block the creation? If not, can you be more clear what you mean when you say the rule does not fire?

Comment: I want to use it kind of as a warning. So they technically can be allowed to create it but hopefully when an error fires and says there is already a record that exists they chose not to create it. Basically when I create 2 accounts with the same appropriate information, nothing happens at all. I want an error to fire to warn them there is already a record with the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions at the bottom aren't doing what I think you think they're doing. :-)

Try creating an account with the name "true" and a city value of "true" - then it should fire.

Conditions tell the duplicate rule what accounts to evaluate. Matching Criteria is actually what defines a match/duplicate. See [Create or Edit Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_create.htm&language=en_US&type=0) for more information.

If your goal is to require that these field values are not blank, then you need to adjust the Matching Criteria in the Matching Rule so that null values are not counted. Right now it's configured to evaluate when there are null values (MatchBlank=TRUE).

Comment: I unchecked the boxes for MATCH BLANK FIELDS and now instead of true it is false. It still is not working. I am confused

Comment: It did work when I used true though. What are the conditions supposed to be for the Duplicate Rule itself?

Comment: @KateCoppola Sorry if I wasn't clear. I don't think you need any Conditions. Your Conditions right now are such that you're restricting all Accounts unless the values of the fields themselves are literally "true"

Comment: Is there a way I can have the restrictions of throwing an error when an Account Name is created more than once? For example, say I named an Account "test". Is there any way that I can have an error thrown when another person tries to make an Account with the name, "test". I still want to have the restrictions that are stated above, but not for the word "true". I want it so that if a person tries to create an Account with the same name it will throw an error.

Comment: Basically, is there a way I can keep these certain conditions where (Account Name AND Site) OR (Account Name AND Billing City), but have it so that it throws an error when a person tries to create one with the same Name and Site, rather than "true". I hope I am making sense. I am new to Salesforce!

Comment: @KateCoppola Yes. Just remove your Conditions. Your Matching Criteria is already set up to do exactly as you just described. Conditions are used to determine whether or not an account should be *evaluated* for duplicates. Your Matching Criteria is what defines a match/duplicate. In this case, duplicates will be found if (Account Name AND Site) OR (Account Name AND Billing City) match.

Comment: OHHH I see now.. it all makes sense now haha. I will try that out.